# Do all C++ compilers allow using a static const int class member variable as an array bound?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static, constants

In VC++ when I need to specify an array bound for a class member variable I do it this way:

```
 class Class {

 private:
     static const int numberOfColors = 16;
     COLORREF colors[numberOfColors];
 };
```

(please don't tell me about using std::vector here)

This way I have a constant that can be used as an array bound and later in the class code to specify loop-statement constraints and at the same time it is not visible anywhere else.

The question is whether this usage of `static const int` member variables only allowed by VC++ or is it typically allowed by other widespread compilers?

Comment: "please don't tell me about using std::vector here" -- no, that wouldn't be appropriate. You should use `std::tr1::array`. `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's 100% legal and should be portable.  The C++ standard says this in 5.19 - Constant expressions" (emphasis mine):

> In several places, C++ requires expressions that evaluate to an integral or enumeration constant: as array bounds (8.3.4, 5.3.4), as case-expressions (6.4.2), as bit-field lengths (9.6), as enumerator initializers (7.2), as static member initializers (9.4.2), and as integral or enumeration non-type template arguments (14.3).
>
> ```
> constant-expression:
>     conditional-expression
> ```
>
> An integral  constant-expression can  involve  only  literals  (2.13),  enumerators, **const variables  or  static data  members  of  integral  or  enumeration  types  initialized  with constant expressions** (8.5), non-type template parameters of integral or enumeration types, and sizeof expressions.

That said, it appears that VC6 doesn't support it.  See [StackedCrooked's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327806/do-all-c-compilers-allow-using-a-static-const-int-class-member-variable-as-an-a/1327847#1327847) for a good workaround. In fact, I generally prefer the `enum` method StackedCrooked mentions for this type of thing.

As an FYI, the "`static const`" technique works in VC9, GCC 3.4.5 (MinGW), Comeau and Digital Mars.

And don't forget that if you use a "`static const'" member, you'll [need a definition for it in addition to the declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257267/is-it-legal-c-to-pass-the-address-of-a-static-const-int-with-no-definition-to-a/1257366#1257366) strictly speaking.  However, virtually all compilers will let you get away with skipping the definition in this case.

Answer (score 14):

This is valid C++ and most (all?) reasonably modern compilers support it. If you are using boost, you can get portable support for this feature in the form of `BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT` macro:

```
class Class {
 private:
     BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(int, numberOfColors = 16);
     COLORREF colors[numberOfColors];
 };
```

The macro is expanded to `static const int numberOfColors = 16` if the compiler supports this, otherwise it resorts to `enum { numberOfColors=16 };`.

Answer (score 13):

That behavior is valid according to the C++ Standard.  Any recent compiler *should* support it.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that Visual Studio 2005 and beyond supports it. The XCode C++ compiler as well (this is gcc actually).

If you want to be safe you could always use the old enum hack that I learned from Effective C++. It goes like this:

```
class Class {

 private:
     enum {
        numberOfColors = 16
     };
     COLORREF colors[numberOfColors];
 };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The enum 'hack' shouldn't be necessary if you're dealing with C++ code, but if you want the declaration to work in C or in VC++6, this is better than the more common method of using #define in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

This has been standard C++ for more than a decade now. It's even supported by VC -- what more could you want? (@Neil: What about SunCC? `:^>`)

Answer (score 3):

Besides other answers you can use following function do determine number of elements in statically alocated arrays:

```
template<typename T, size_t length>
size_t arrayLength(T (&a)[length])
{
    return length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that this will also work with gcc and Solaris, but I can't verify this at the moment.

In the future you could extend the idea like this:

```
template<int size>
class Class {
private:
    COLORREF colors[size];
};
```

and use it like this:

```
Class<5> c;
```

so that you are not limited to exactly one buffer size in your application.

Comment: You are using a magic number, which is what the question was trying to avoid.

Comment: @Neil: However, the magic number 5 above could be replaced by a `static const int` from a class that 'c' might find itself a member of.

Answer (score 1):

I've stopped bothering about the portability of that years ago.  There are perhaps still compilers which don't support it, but I haven't met any of them recently.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to answer questions like this by referencing the ISO C++ speicifcation but the spec is hard for people to get and harder to read.
I think the simplest answer hinges on two things:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 and up is a relatively conformant C++ implementation. If it allows you to do something, chances are its standard.
- Download something like Code::Blocks to get a GCC compiler to try stuff out. If it works in MS and GCC, chances really are, its standard.

Comment: The spec is very easy to get (for $30): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-x-standard/83763#83763  Reading the spec is a different story, but serious C++ prgrammers should probably still refer to it from time to time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123455/should-every-c-programmer-read-the-iso-standard-to-become-professional